# Asignar objeto a una coordenada

Tags: java

Soy nuevo en Java y me piden en un método que asigne el objeto Cell pasado como parámetro a la coordenada pasada también como parámetro. Os adjunto el resumen de las clases

```
public class Level {

    private Cell[][] board;

    private void setCell(Coordinate coord, Cell cell) throws LevelException {
        if(validatePosition(coord)) {
            board[coord.getRow()][coord.getColumn()] = cell; // El error se encuentra aquí!
        }
        throw new LevelException(LevelException.ERROR_COORDINATE);
    }

public class Cell {

    private Coordinate coordinate;
    private Level level;

    public Cell (int row, int column) {setCoordinate(row, column);}

    public Coordinate getCoordinate() {
        return coordinate;
    }

    protected void setCoordinate(int row, int column){
        this.coordinate = new Coordinate(row,column);
    }

public class Coordinate {
    private int row;
    private int column;

    public Coordinate (int row, int column) {setRow(row); setColumn(column);}

    public int getRow() {
        return this.row;
    }
    private void setRow(int row) {this.row = row;}

    public int getColumn() {
        return this.column;
    }
    private void setColumn(int column) {this.column = column;}
```

Los tipos de accesos de los métodos no debo modificarlos. El error viene ya que estoy asignando el objeto a la coordenada del tablero y no la del parámetro. Alguien sabría como puedo corregirlo?

Gracias

EDIT: error

```
    private void setCell(Coordinate coord, Cell cell) throws LevelException {
        if(validatePosition(coord)) {
            Cell[][] board = new Cell[coord.getRow()][coord.getColumn()];
            board[coord.getRow()][coord.getColumn()] = cell;
        }
        throw new LevelException(LevelException.ERROR_COORDINATE);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay varios detalles con el codigo:

1. Parece que las clases no estan cerradas correctamente con su llave correspondiente. Imagino que fue algun error al copiar.
2. En la clase Level aparece una excepcion que no existe (LevelException). A menos que la hayas creado, deberias cambiarlo solo por Exception o cualquiera otra que se acople a lo que quieres hacer
3. Finalmente, el error te sale porque no has inicializado el arreglo llamado board y estan intentando asignarle valores antes de inicializarlo.
   Puede inicializarlo de la siguiente manera

`private Cell[][] board = new Cell[2][2];//el numero representa el tamano del arreglo`

En el arreglo anterior esta inicializado como 2x2 pero debes tener en cuenta los valores que va a traer el metodo getRow() y getColumn() para asignarle el tamaño correcto

Comment: Gracias por responder, del primer y segundo es tal como dices, no hay problema. He añadido el arreglo anterior en el método y sigue dando el mismo error. Es correcto como lo he hecho?

Comment: podrias compartir el mensaje de error que te sale?